# Spring-boot how to open port 8080 to be accessed externally on same wifi lan on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, spring, macos, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application running locally on my Mac Big Sur that was started like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=development
```

In my application-development.properties file I have the following configuration:

```
server.port = 8080
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

I wish to launch the spring-boot application locally on my mac laptop so that I could access the API from another device that is connected to the same WIFI as my laptop. I tried accessing the api from a mobile phone by opening a browser and connecting to the mac's public IP address like this: mac-public-ip:8080/api-path.. But no success.

What I've tried is disabling the firewall of mac completely, but no help. Also I tried to access the api through Mac computer name.local as instructed in mac's system preferences sharing section, but no help. From the sharing section I have set up Internet Sharing on, but that doesn't seem to help either. Im clueless what to do.

Spring-boot version: 2.3.0

Comment: What does it says?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Connecting to the public IP won't work unless the router has a port foward configured *and* supports hairpin NAT. `name.local` *might* work, depending on a number of things. Try connecting with the Mac's private IP address, and see if that works. If it does, then start adding complications and see when it breaks.

Comment: Connecting to the Mac's private IP address worked, thx!